How to get decimals as values into the result of gdal.Polygonize() function using Python3?
I'm using gdal.Polygonize() function to vectorize main regions in a raster. It works so good!
But, the pixel values considered for the vectorization are just integers, so the clustering ignores data groups between each integer. My code is as follows:
rasterDS = gdal.Open(raster)
band = rasterDS.GetRasterBand(1)

# Create and prepare a new layer for the polygonized layer
proj = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=rasterDS.GetProjectionRef())
polygonizedLayer = destDS.CreateLayer(name, srs=proj)
field = ogr.FieldDefn("ND", ogr.OFTInteger)  # Deffine the attribute for Digital Level
polygonizedLayer.CreateField(field)   # Add the field created before into layer schema
ndField = polygonizedLayer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldIndex("ND") # Get the field index where ND going to be stored

# Generate the polygons
gdal.Polygonize(band, band, polygonizedLayer, ndField, ['8CONNECTED=8'], callback=None)

Is there a way to make the vectorization considering decimal values and so the features into the layer have values with a precision of two decimals at least?

GridOptions() takes an outputType= option, perhaps setting that to gdal.GDT_Float32 (or 64) would allow your fractional results.

Thank you so much. My question was wrong. I already edited, hope you could help me
